# How do I pass Meteor Subscription Data into React Component Props using ES6

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Given this subscription, and the React Component below, how do I pass the subscription data in as props 'searchTerms'? Most of the documentation I can find refers to using mixins, but as far as I understand this is an anti pattern in ES6. Thanks!

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    subscription: {
      searchResult: Meteor.subscribe("search", searchValue)
    }
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchWrapper 
        searchTerms={this.state.subscription.searchResult} 
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Vijay, this approach is way easier to read. Will start following this approach

Comment: The result of Meteor.subscribe is a handle. The actual data is available in minimongo. Querying the mongo collection and storing that result in the state will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options when it comes to creating containers in Meteor. My personal favorite is [react-komposer](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-komposer).

Here's what your container would look like using `react-komposer`. Note that a container is simply a component that just passes data, and in the case of Meteor, provides reactivity.

After `npm install --save react-komposer`, create a container using:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';

import Component from '../components/Component.jsx';
import { Collection } from '../../api/collection/collection.js';

// Creates a container composer with necessary data for component
const composer = ( props, onData ) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('Collection.list');

  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const collection = Collection.find().fetch(); // must use fetch
    onData(null, {collection});
  }
};

// Creates the container component and links to Meteor Tracker
export default composeWithTracker(composer)(Component);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really straightfoward

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is to use the react-meteor-data package.

```
meteor add react-meteor-data
```

Then create a container as follows:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import SearchWrapper from '../pages/SearchWrapper.jsx';
import { SearchResults } from '../../api/searchResults.js';

export default SearchResultContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {
  const { searchValue } = params;
  const searchHandle = Meteor.subscribe('search', searchValue);
  const loading = !searchHandleHandle.ready();
  const results = SearchResults.find().fetch();
  const resultsExist = !loading && !!list;
  return {
    loading,
    results,
    resultsExist,
  };
}, SearchWrapper);
```

The returned object from the container is available as props in the wrapped component - SearchWrapper.